# Must not query elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have my request:

```
{
    "size": 10, 
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {"term": {"event": "matchmaking_done"}}
                ]
            }
        },
           "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "gt"  : "2016-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "lte" : "2016-06-01T00:05:00.000Z"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "user-ids" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "user_id",
                "size": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I need to add into this request parameter - does not contain field `pvp_league`! I tried add `must_not` but can't understand how to do this correct.
Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered it yourself, but the ES 2.x way to do this is to *not* use the `filtered` query because it has been deprecated and it will be removed in ES 5.0. ES 2.x introduces the concept of the "filter" context rather than every query being either just a query or a filter; now every query is both a filter or a query (scored), just depending on the context it's used in.

For your query, this therefore becomes a little simpler because of the simplified `bool` / `filter` syntax:

```
{  
  "size":10,
  "query":{  
    "bool":{  
      "must":[  
        {  
          "term":{  
            "event":"matchmaking_done"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not":[  
        {  
          "exists":{  
            "field":"pvp_league"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter":[  
        {  
          "range":{  
            "@timestamp":{  
              "gt":"2016-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
              "lte":"2016-06-01T00:05:00.000Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs":{  
    "user-ids":{  
      "terms":{  
        "field":"user_id",
        "size":0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As a very big aside, specifying `"size" : 0` for the `terms` aggregation, you are requesting *all* unique terms, up to `INT_MAX`. That is not a scalable request (works great with 10 user_ids, or even 100, but not 10000 users).

As a not-so-bad aside, your request doesn't need a query context at all because nothing about the *search* side of it cares about relevance. Your term *query* (`"event" : "matchmaking_done"`) either matches or it doesn't. Since you either want it to match or not, but you don't really care about order inherently, you should use this in the filter context. This changes the request to:

```
{  
  "size": 10,
  "query": {  
    "bool": {  
      "must_not": [  
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "pvp_league"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter":[
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gt":"2016-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
              "lte":"2016-06-01T00:05:00.000Z"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "event": "matchmaking_done"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "user-ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution! It looks like this:

```
{
    "size": 10, 
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {"term": {"event": "matchmaking_done"}}
                ],
                "must_not": [
                    {"filtered": {
                        "filter": {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "pvp_league"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
            }
        },
           "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "gt"  : "2016-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "lte" : "2016-06-01T00:05:00.000Z"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "user-ids" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "user_id",
                "size": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```